# How can I control the input with sentinel value 0?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a problem where I have to take the input integers of users until users enter 0, then I have to reverse those words using a function.

I have written a code that works partially but it also gives the output 0 at the end, but the problem doesn't ask for 0 to be printed.

I have tried to fix it, but cannot find a way out.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reverse(int num) {
  int rem = 0;

  while (num != 0) {
    rem = rem * 10 + num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
  }

  cout << rem << endl;
}

int main() {
  int num;

  while (num != 0) {
    cin >> num;
    reverse(num);

    if (num == 0)
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity to practice debugging. Go through your code line-by-line and explain to yourself why each line is correct. Be sure to go over how you stop before printing the zero.

Comment: Well you do `reverse(num)` before your `if(num==0)` check so `reverse` is also done for `0`.

Comment: An additional note `int num;` does not initialize `num`, so when the loop is entered ` num != 0` check is done on a not initialized variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    int num = -1;
    while (num != 0) {
        if (cin >> num) {
            if (num == 0) {
                break;
            }
            reverse(num);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this will help you and you learn something.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agreed. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hope it is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Take input first to avoid garbage values, then proceed to reverse if and only if the number is not equal to zero and a variable with valid type for cin is entered. (i.e. for an integer type variable, cin would expect an integer. Otherwise it will trigger its failbit)

```cpp
int main()
{
  int num;
  do { cin>>num;
       if(n==0 || !cin) // or !cin.good()
         break;
       reverse(num);
     } while(!num=0)
     return 0;
}
```

---

Examples:

Input:

```
314
51
hello
```

Output:

```
413
15
```

---

Input:

```
23
0
```

Output:

```
32
```